# Wordpress Edit Page adding a Closing Shortcode tag Automatically

Tags: wordpress

I have the following content in the posts

```
 This is content
 [divider space="123" anything="123"]
 [another]this is content[/another]
 more content
 [divider]
 some more text or shortcodes
```

if you notice in the above shortcode the [divider] shortocode does not have the closing tag, it can have attributes, so those should remain intact but while editing the post in WP Admin it should automatically add the closing shortcode. The desired content while editing post should be:

```
 This is content
 [divider space="123" anything="123"][/divider]
 [another]this is content[/another]
 more content
 [divider][/divider]
 some more text or shortcodes
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: A shortcode do not muste have a closing tag.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. I know shortcode should not have a closing tag necessarily, but in my code I need to have a closing tag. My question ism when I edit a page in Wp Admin, it should check if the [divide] shortcode is in the page content, it should automatically close [/divider] in the editing page.

Comment: Ideally I wanted to do this with jQuery and Regex, but I didnt get any her here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128995/adding-closing-tag-shortcode-with-jquery-regex